# File Upload in Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, file, io, flask

I am trying to pass a file into MongoDB from flask. The file doesn't seem to be uploading properly in order to put it into my database. I think the function to insert it into the database itself is also not working exactly right. I'm not sure what's wrong though as i'm sure it's very close.

```
def put_file(file_name, room_number):
    db_conn = get_db()
    with open('uploads/'+file_name, "r") as f:
        gfs.put(f, room=room_number)
    gfs = gridfs.GridFS(db_conn)

@app.route('/upload',methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    #get the name of the uploaded file
    file=request.files['file']
    #print "requested files"
    space=request.form['space']
    # if the file exists make it secure
    if file and space: #if the file exists
        #make the file same, remove unssopurted chars
        filename=secure_filename(file.filename)
        #move the file to our uploads folder
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],file.name))
        put_file(filename,space)
        # remove the file from disk as we don't need it anymore after database insert.
        os.unlink(os.path.join( app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] , filename))
        # maybe redirect user to the uploaded_file route, which will show the uploaded file.
        return render_template('index.html')#, filename = filename ,space = space) ##take the file name
    else:
        return render_template('invalid.html')
```

Comment: What does your template look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in your `file.save()` call:

```
file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.name))
```

That won't work.

Instead of using `file.name`, use the variable `filename` that you created instead:

```
file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```